# How to set the settings icon in the app settings on Android?

Tags: android, settings

I saw on many apps, for example Trello, that they have set an green icon next to the app settings in the main settings on Android. Here's an example:

[image: Example of Trello's implementation]

Now how can I do this with Android Studio for my own app?

Comment: That's actually the application icon.

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>